# Microsoft Chart Controls (MSChart) - cannot find Dundas.Extensions namespace API

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, dundas

I'm trying to use ThresholdLineHelper Class in my chart project, but it seems like Microsoft haven't exposed Dundas.Extensions namespace into MSChart library. 
Does anyone know where I could find it or use some workaround?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Microsoft has nothing to do with `Dundas.Extensions`.

Comment: I think you wanted `Dundas Chart V7.0`

Comment: Why not? They bought Dundas Charting controls and released MSChart. Dundas.Extensions is a part of Dundas Charting control library.

Comment: which dot net framework are you using ? It could be part of 4.0 not sure

Comment: Nope, .net 4.0 System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll does not contain it.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that simple threshold line could be created using:

- `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.StripLine` for a threshold line
- `Chart.DataManipulator.Statistics.Mean` to extract mean value of the series

There's a sample for web, but also works for windows forms charts:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.stripline.aspx